# AngularJS dynamic directives for extensibility

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've seen this question asked a few times with different causes for inquire; I believe this differs enough to warrant a new question.

An application I'm working on supports extensibility via a plugin architecture. The backend (.NET) supports adding new plugin assemblies which extend the backend functionality. Often, they also contain JS/HTML/etc. resources which are pre-loaded on the front end, to allow the end user to utilize the extended functionality.

My current design choice is that plugins contain a JS resource which registers directives/components to the AngularJS application module. The *problem* is dynamically (conditionally) adding rendering these directives.

Say a plugin extends the data sources supported for a given thing (reporting, or whatever). The end user selects from a drop down one of the plugin sources. This would require the end user to select additional plugin-specific settings. So far as I can tell, encapsulating the UI/functionally details into a `<foo-plugin-data-source />` is the sanest option. But, **how do I conditionally/programmatically render that directive**?

My searches keep bringing me to `$compile`, and I can probably hack together something with it; but I'm curious if there's something "cleaner".

Something like, in an intermediate container directive:

```
var name = 'fooPluginDataSource';
var directive = $directiveLoader.load(name, { opts });
element.append(directive);
```

What's the most sane-and-orderly way to load directives programmatically rather than declaratively, based on some state?

Comment: As far as I know a plugin could affect the application in lots of different ways. Also, by saying `Directive` you mean Component Directives? New pages? It seems more like an architectural question because if you'd like to seek a more strict plugin approach you'd may end up with something like Wordpress does, your plugins change `things` on your app to add new feature, settings, etc.

Comment: I do specifically mean directives and/or components; in order to isolate scope and state. The backend plugin architecture is sound, and the nature of the plugins does not permit them to expose whole pages of content. Plugins do not communicate with each other at the UI layer, and only use core services exposed by the application. I just want a clean way of dynamically specifying which plugin directive to render.

Comment: Well, your own suggestion seems to be the way to go, create a directive that render directives. So that you can apply conditionals and dynamically define it. For example:  `<plugin name="thePlugin.name" options="thePlugin.options"></plugin>`, then from the directive declarations you can compile (even though it might look a bit ugly). It'll also imply on your plugin directive structure. I'll add an example answer, but it seems not to have a prettier way.

Comment: The far easiest option would be to use attributes directives.
Then you can configure your UI to add attributes on fly to objects. Note that if you needing bindings with form data, you would need to use the ngModelController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a directive to compile the plugin using controlled data like so:

```
<plugin name="'my-plugin-directive'" options="options"></plugin>
```

Working example bellow:

```js
angular
  .module('myPluginModule', [])
  .directive('myPluginDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        a: '=',
        b: '='
      },
      template: '<br>a: {{ a }}<br>b.c: {{b.c}}<br>b.d: {{b.d}}'
    };
  });

angular
  .module('app', ['myPluginModule'])
  .directive('plugin', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '=',
        options: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, $element) {

        var attrs = Object.keys($scope.options)
          .map(function(opt) {
            return opt + '="options.' + opt + '"';
          }).join(' ');

        var template = '<' +
          $scope.name +
          (attrs !== '' ? ' ' + attrs : '') +
          '></' + $scope.name + '>';

console.log(template);

        var elemt = $compile(template)($scope);
        $element.append(elemt);
      }
    };
  })
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="options = {a:1, b: {c:2, d:3}}">
  <plugin name="'my-plugin-directive'" options="options"></plugin>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was definitely the easiest way to go. I was stumbling in this direction, but your example works exactly as I need. I've customized as needed, and using ES6 inline templates it's not that ugly. Thank you!

Comment: I'll post a plunker when I get to work; I've used a service to map objects/types to directives, so the UI extension points can resolve which directive to render (usually determined by state change to an aforementioned object/type)

Comment: @Dan, Yes please, I'd like to see the final approach.